# C# Error: “Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.”

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, client

I have problem with this error:

> C# Error: “Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been
>   initialized.”

I lloked ower others threads, but people have it built their clients little different and it didnt help.
I dont know, why this error showed. And I suppose its wrong somewhere at `SelectOsoba`.
I need to show data in DataGridView.

**my code is :**

```
class Vrstva
{
    public static SqlConnection myConnection;
    public static string connstr;
    static DataTable t;

    public static void createConnect1()
    {
        connstr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["local1"];
        Vrstva.myConnection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    }
    public static void createConnect2()
    {
        connstr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["local2"];
        Vrstva.myConnection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    }
    public static void createConnect3()
    {
        connstr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["local3"];
        Vrstva.myConnection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    }
    public static void openConn()
    {
        Vrstva.myConnection.Open();
    }
    public static void closeConn()
    {
        Vrstva.myConnection.Close();
    }
    public static SqlDataAdapter Query(string command)
    {
        return new SqlDataAdapter(command, Vrstva.myConnection);
    }
    public static void NonQuery(string command)
    {
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(command, Vrstva.myConnection);
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    public static bool login1(string login, string password)
    {
        string login1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["login1"];
        string password1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password1"];
        if (login == login1 && password == password1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    public static bool login2(string login, string password)
    {
        string login1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["login2"];
        string password1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password2"];
        if (login == login1 && password == password1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    public static bool login3(string login, string password)
    {
        string login1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["login3"];
        string password1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password3"];
        if (login == login1 && password == password1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    ////vypis tabulku prislusniku
    public static DataTable SelectOsoba()
    {
        t = new DataTable();
        Query("Select * from Osoba;").Fill(t);
        return t;
    }
    //Insert
    public static void PridejOsoba(string Jmeno, string Prijmeni, string Povolani, int Poc_Det)
    {
        NonQuery("Insert into Osoba(Jmeno,Prijmeni,Povolani,Poc_Det) values('" + Jmeno + "','" + Prijmeni + "','" + Povolani + "','" + Poc_Det + "');");
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from that being a really horrible way of wrapping db operations (everything static! Yuck! What sort of program is going to use this?) you probably haven't created the connection. I don't know because you haven't shown the calling code, but that's what I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely being thrown because your connection in this line:

```
return new SqlDataAdapter(command, Vrstva.myConnection);
```

has not been initialized.

You have to call one of your `createConnectX()` methods before trying to query.